# how to add data into a specific column at runtime in grid

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, grid, telerik, asp.net-3.5

```
I have a rad grid, i have bounded the columns in the grid using GripBoundColumns which shows me dropdown cloumns when i edit the record, Insert/update/delete are working fine for me.


My question is it possible to insert new data into the column(Not the whole record just only to one column) when i edit the record.

For example...

suppose i have 5 columns (Client Name, Account No, Account name, account status, Custodian Dealer)

CustodianDealer is my drop down coloumn and data for it comes from different table

when i edit or insert a new record in the grid, i can select the existing Custodiandealers in the table.

now if i want to insert a new record to the custodianDealer table not to the grid, how can i acheive it
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this within the ItemDataBound event:

```
If TypeOf (e.Item) Is GridDataItem Then
    Dim GDI As GridDataItem = CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)

    GDI([ColumnNameAsString]).Text = "Some custom text"
End If
```

The GridDataItem is essentially a TableCell, so you can add controls as needed.

Oh, and if it wasn't clear from my notation, "[ColumnNameAsString]" is your own column name.

Answer (score 0):

Wire the grid insert command and execute an insert query which updates merely the Custodiandealers table with a new entry. To display it in the dropdown editor, make sure the new record has a foreign relation with the grid main table source as the rest of the items in the Custodiandealers table.

Comment: can you provide me with a small example the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm reading your problem correctly, you are trying to insert a record into the custodianDealer table based on some changes made during edit/insert.

If that's the case, you can handle the ItemCommand event and update your datatable based on those changes.

Can you provide the exact details of the use case?

Comment: there may be a possibility that new custodiandealer may be needed to be added or edited by the user at runtime

Comment: This is going to be difficult to help you solve the problem if you don't provide some more detailed information about your problem. Can you provide a screenshot of the UI with some comments about which how a new custodianDealer will be added? Will it be added from the grid? From another form field outside the grid? It sounds like the list is a dropdown, so are you using the Telerik ComboBox to allow text entries into the field? Please be as specific as possible, it will help you get your answer much more quickly.